# how to get the value from a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss, google-api

I am relatively new to javascript and I am facing some difficulty.I have two java script files as I have shown below. I am having trouble getting the value of the variable **entry_title** inside the getRss function and storing it inside the variables **Rss1_title** and **Rss2_title** . Creating a global variable and assigning it to **entry_title** will make things worse as I will not be able to know from which Rss url the title came from. Is there a easy way to get the value of the callback functions ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsRss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="notification.js"></script>
```

My notification.js file

```
    function get_rss1_feeds(){
        var Rss1_title = getRss("http://yofreesamples.com/category/free-coupons/feed/?type=rss");
    }

    function get_rss2_feeds(){
        var Rss2_title = getRss("http://yofreesamples.com/category/real-freebies/feed/?type=rss");  
    }
setTimeout('get_rss1_feeds()',8000);
setTimeout('get_rss2_feeds()',7000);
```

My jsRss.js file:

```
function getRss(url){

    if(url == null) return false;

    google.load("feeds", "1");

    // Our callback function, for when a feed is loaded.
    function feedLoaded(result) {
        if (!result.error) {

            var entry = result.feed.entries[0];             
            var entry_title = entry.title;      // need to get this value           
        }

    }       
    function Load() {
        // Create a feed instance that will grab feed.
        var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(url);
        // Calling load sends the request off.  It requires a callback function.
        feed.load(feedLoaded);              
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(Load);             
}
```

Errors :

When the setTimeout(get_rss1_feeds, 8000); method is called I get a blank screen. 
I get a error in my console saying **octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated** and it is pointing to the 6th line in this script.
Is it because I am using google-api for parsing my Rss?

```
if (window['google'] != undefined && window['google']['loader'] != undefined) {
if (!window['google']['feeds']) {
window['google']['feeds'] = {};
google.feeds.Version = '1.0';
google.feeds.JSHash = '8992c0a2cdf258e5bd0f517c78243cd6';
google.feeds.LoadArgs = 'file\75feeds\46v\0751';
}
google.loader.writeLoadTag("css", google.loader.ServiceBase + "/api/feeds/1.0/8992c0a2cdf258e5bd0f517c78243cd6/default+en.css", false);
google.loader.writeLoadTag("script", google.loader.ServiceBase + "/api/feeds/1.0/8992c0a2cdf258e5bd0f517c78243cd6/default+en.I.js", false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as it's a different scope, you can either return it in a callback, or provide it in another way such as exporting it to a higher scope that is visible to your desired location. In this case, it's the global scope, so I'd advise against that.

```
function getRss(url, callback) {
//...
function feedLoaded(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[0];
        var entry_title = entry.title; // need to get this value
        callback && callback(entry_title);        
    }
}
```

and call it like so,

```
function get_rss1_feeds() {
    var Rss1_title = getRss("http://yofreesamples.com/category/free-coupons/feed/?type=rss", function(entry_title) {
        // This scope has access to entry_title
    });
}
```

As an aside, use your setTimeout like so:

```
setTimeout(get_rss1_feeds, 8000);
```

rather than

```
setTimeout("get_rss1_feeds()", 8000);
```

as the latter uses eval, whereas the former passes a reference to the function.

Comment: wow that was an interesting solution. I will try it out. thanks Robert

Comment: It works perfectly if I call **get_rss1_feeds()** directly without using **setTimeout(get_rss1_feeds, 8000);**  If I use it my browser shows a blank page and it tries to reload !!! any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: When I try to view page source also I am not able to see anything!!

Comment: @Yeshwanth Venkatesh: You must have changed something else. Check for console errors or blank `document.write` calls.

Comment: I am not sure what that error is!! every thing works perfectly without the setTimeout , I also tired using setInterval but it dint work

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough it will make your code a mess, you can append the variables to the window object.
For example:

```
function a()
{
 window.testStr = "test";

}

function b()
{
 alert(window.testStr);
}
```

Or even create your own object, instead of using window, as such:

```
var MyRSSReader = {
 TitleOne : '',
 TitleTwo : '' 
} 

MyRSSReader.TitleOne = "My title";
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) has a nice article about global variables, and why they are bad.

Comment: Since there are two Rss urls if i have a global variable I will not be able to keep track of which Rss feed's title it is storing!!

Comment: Just set a different variable in each function, as you do now?

Comment: Yes that sound good. But Heuvel I really wanted to avoid global variables. your solution was very nice thanks for the wikipedia article !!