# setTimeout problem with Google Feed API

Tags: javascript, rss, settimeout, setinterval, google-feed-api

I have used google feed API to read a Rss feed url and display the title. When I call the function **get_rss1_feeds** directly It works fine. But when I call it with setTimeout or setInterval I am able to see only blank screen and the page does not stop loading!!

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyA5m1Nc8ws2BbmPRwKu5gFradvD_hgq6G0" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="query.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsRss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="notification.js"></script>
```

My notification.js

```
/** global variable **/
var Rsstitle;
/** end global variable **/

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
// Empty
}

function get_rss1_feeds() {
    console.log('test');               // this is being outputted
    var Rss1_title = getRss("http://yofreesamples.com/category/free-coupons/feed/?type=rss", function(entry_title) {    
        if(Rsstitle != entry_title)
        Rsstitle = entry_title;
        console.log('test1',Rsstitle); // not working
    });   
}

//get_rss1_feeds() works fine
setTimeout(get_rss1_feeds,5000);
```

My jsRss.js file

```
    function getRss(url, callback){
    console.log('test2');            // this is being outputted 
    if(url == null) return false;
    google.load("feeds", "1");
    // Our callback function, for when a feed is loaded.
    function feedLoaded(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[0];
            var entry_title = entry.title; // need to get this value
            callback && callback(entry_title);        
        }
    }
    function Load() {
        // Create a feed instance that will grab feed.
        var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(url);
        // Calling load sends the request off.  It requires a callback function.
        feed.load(feedLoaded);      
    }    
    google.setOnLoadCallback(Load);             
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a breakpoint in the `getRss()` function and see what's going on when it's called from `setTimeout()`.  My guess would be that something in that function has a scoping issue and isn't available from the global scope that setTimeout runs in, but is available from the normal scope you tried it in.  It could be variables or it could be functions that aren't available.

This can sometimes happen if functions are declared inside another function and thus aren't actually available globally.

FYI, this block of code is very odd:

```
var Rsstitle;
if(Rsstitle != entry_title)         
Rsstitle = entry_title;
```

You can replace it with this:

```
var Rsstitle = entry_title;
```

Comment: I did console.log() inside the getRss() function and it seems its not going inside the function. I actually had initial problem of getting the value from the call back function. [link to my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946711/how-to-get-the-value-from-a-callback-function). This is almost a continuation of that.

Comment: Once I get the value every 5000 ms I want to make sure I dont display the same title again and again. Just to avoid duplications !!

Comment: If `getRSS()` is not getting called, then there must be some sort of scope issue when calling it from `get_rss1_feeds()`.  Put a console.log as the first line of `get_rss1_feeds()` and make sure it's getting called.  If you want to compare this title to the previous title, then you need to move this declaration `var Rsstitle;` to the top level scope so it can be a global variable that will last from one call to the next.  As you have it now, it's a local variable that is recycled as soon as `get_rss1_feeds()` exits so it's not accomplishing anything.

Comment: We can really only help you solve a scoping issue if we can see the entirety of your existing code, not just the pieces you've pasted here.  If they're in publicly accessible .js files, just giving us a link to the files will do.

Comment: I did just as you said. console.log at the start of both the functions are being outputted (I have documented it inside the code). This is the entire code I am working on. I am planing to use more than one Rss feed so I will be creating similar functions like get_rss2_feeds etc and each of them will have there own setTimeout method which will be calling them at unique time intervals.

Comment: The ideal way to do this is to just set a breakpoint at the first line of getRss and just step through it to see where it goes wrong.  The built-in Chrome debugger works great.  If you don't use Chrome, then Firebug is a free add-on for Firefox and it works well too.  This will show you exactly where it fails.  If you don't want to do that (but you really should), then you can just slowly move the console.log() line through your function until you find where it stops outputting when it should (but this is the slow way to debug).

Comment: Is there a tutorial explaining how to do breakpoint. I have never done this before and I was curious could you explain why my page gets refreshed when settimeout method is called ?

Comment: I'd suggest you do a little searching on Google - there's a ton of useful stuff that you can find yourself on pretty much any topic.  For example, here's the help page for the Chrome debugger: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html.

Comment: ok I did debug it using the breakpoint in my chrome as you said.I set the breakpoint on my getrss function the page is being displayed when the breakpoint move to **google.setOnLoadCallback(Load);** the page goes blank. Then it comes out of getRss function and comes out of get_rss1_feeds() function.

Comment: are you able to figure out the problem ?

Comment: I can't solve your problem via inspection here as it uses a libraries I don't know and I don't know how they work and without a functioning web page that I could set my own breakpoints in, I can't debug it myself.

Comment: [dynamic loader](http://code.google.com/intl/af/apis/loader/#Dynamic) i think This might be the answer .. guess have to load the google feed api dynamically !!